# this.props is empty in React Router v6

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I have this component which is basically a button that adds an Employee to a database:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import EmployeeService from "../services/EmployeeService";
class ListEmployeeComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      employees: [],
    };
    this.addEmployee=this.addEmployee.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    EmployeeService.getEmployees().then((res) => {
      this.setState({ employees: res.data });
    });
  }
  addEmployee(){
    console.log(this.props.history);
    this.props.history.push("/create");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2 className="text-center">Employees List</h2>
          <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.addEmployee} >Add Employee</button>
       
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ListEmployeeComponent;
```

However, `this.props` is `{}` and so `this.props.history` is `undefined`..

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
    at ListEmployeeComponent.addEmployee
```

and this is the instantiation of the component:

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" exact element={<ListEmployeeComponent />}></Route>
</Routes>
```

```json
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
```

Comment: Even if there was no issue here, **avoid altering props**. It's an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use react-router6 then you need to use react hooks to pass router data and there are 2 options:

1. rewrite your class component to a functional one;
2. create a functional wrapper around your class component - https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8146#issuecomment-947860640

also an example from the issue thread:

```js
import React,{ Component} from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const  withNavigation = (Component : Component) => {
  return props => <Component {...props} navigate={useNavigate()} />;
} 

//classComponent  
class LoginPage extends React.Component{

submitHandler =(e) =>{
    //successful login 
    this.props.navigate('/dashboard');
  }
}
export default withNavigation(LoginPage);
```

Comment: I second the functional wrapper approach.

Answer (score -2):

use render to prop pattern as shown below:
This will pass all routing related properties to your component( in react router 4)

```
 <Route
    path="/"
    exact
    render={(props: any) => <ListEmployeeComponent {...props} />}  
  ></Route>
```

In react router 6:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

use const history = createBrowserHistory(); in your component to access
```

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

use like this < ListEmployeeComponent history={useNavigate()} />
```

To use location:
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

Comment: in react-router6 Router component does not have props render

Comment: @AndreySmolko please check updated answer that may clear your doubts

Comment: I am sorry but I do not get why we need to export createBrowserHistory? OP asks about props propagation and I replied that we need to use functional wrapper for class component.

Comment: He might need history to get path, param or may be to navigate so i have given all possible options through my comment.